# How to get itemcount data from ListView and share to any other pages/widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart

**I am new in flutter I want to show the itemcount data from Streambuilder listview builder to the dashboard of another widget. Please help**

**My file inside listview.dart is:**

```
 Flexible(
     child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: DatabaseManager.orderStream(isAscending),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                     final value = snapshot.data!.docs;
                     return value.isEmpty
                              ? const Center(
                                   child: Text(AppString.noAvailableOrder),
                                      )
                                    : ListView.builder(
                                        itemCount: value.length,
                                        itemBuilder: (context, i) => OrderListData(
                                              id: value[i].id,
                                              location: value[i]["recLocation"],
                                              phoneNo: value[i]["recPhone"],
                                              recName: value[i]["recName"],
                                            ),
                                          );
                                       },
                                     ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                             ),
                         );
                       }
           
                     },
               );
         }
```

**I want to show item count data in dashboard.dart :**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare `final value` before the `@override Widget` like `var value` and then in the `Steam builder` write `setState(() => value = snapshot.data!.docs)`. Now you can use `value` while pushing in the navigator.

Answer (score 0):

> You have to call init()function on `dashboard.dart` for retrieving the
> length of data,which will be available by futurebuilder in `utils.dart`(All dbhelpers and builders are written here) file.
> Then For intial data retrieval make a seperate file for Futurebuilders and retrieve
> data by variable. Or you can intialize Futurebuilder in main.dart also
> which is basically good method.